# typescript generic types in array getting lost

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to get an instance of a Sequence class that has an array of different Request objects which are basically following the same pattern. Each of those objects has an `operation` property (i.e. string), and a property of whatever value that `operation` is.

The problem is I don't have a clue how to keep those Request object types when I pass them to this Sequence class.

Now, I might have misunderstood the generics, might over engineered this, might have redundancy. Basically only requirement for this is that I have a Sequence class that has all those Requests and I can have some typescript magic

Hope you could help me with this

```
// using this to get around the generic Request class in Sequence class
class BaseRequest {}

class Request<T> extends BaseRequest {
  constructor(params: T) {
    super();
    Object.assign(this, params);
  }
}

class Sequence {
  requests: BaseRequest[];

  add(request: BaseRequest) {
    this.requests.push(requests);
  }

  merge(sequence: Sequence) {
    this.requests = this.requests.concat(sequence.requests);
  }
}

const RequestBuilder = <T>(payload: T) => {
  return <T>new Request(<T>payload);
}

interface CreateJobRequest {
  operation: 'createJob';
  createJob: any;
}

const params: CreateJobRequest = {
  operation: 'createJob',
  createJob: {},
};

let request = RequestBuilder(params);
let sequence = new Sequence();
sequence.requests.push(request);
```

now, when I try to access that request, I get:

```
// Property 'operation' does not exist on type 'BaseRequest'
if (sequence.requests[0].operation === '') {}
```

this doesn't help either (without the builder)

```
class JobRequest extends BaseRequest implements CreateJobRequest {
  operation: 'createJob' = 'createJob';
  createJob: any = {};

  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}

let sequence = new Sequence();
sequence.requests.push(new JobRequest());
```

Comment: Why would TS know that what you've defined as `BaseRequest` is specifically `JobRequest` without you ever verifying that?

Comment: @VLAZ thank you, and sorry for my stupidity :), but I was kind of asking that, or get around that somehow

Comment: Are you saying you need the requests array to be a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) that remembers exactly which type of element exists at a given index?  If so, there's no good way in the type system to represent what happens when you concatenate two tuples together (so `merge()` will be hard to type) and even appending onto the end of a tuple requires a lot of hoop jumping (so `add()` will be annoying to type).  And if you mutate the array prop directly `sequence.requests.push()` it's hopeless, since mutation is hard to represent.

Comment: I think I need to see a fuller use case here that shows how you intend to interact with a `Sequence` containing requests of more than just one type.  I mean, if you're okay with a particular sequence holding an `Array<{operation: unknown}>` that's fine, but if you need to keep track of subtypes of `{operation: unknown}` at different positions in the array there will be issues.

Comment: @jcalz I'm not sure I understood "okay with `operation: unknown`". Later on, somewhere, I need to loop through those objects (requests) and check their types and act accordingly... I could be an instance check if that helps with the typings. H.B.'s answer works with one request but when trying to merge different types, it goes south. Typescript can be a real hardcore with generics -- browsing your past answers :)

Comment: It would help if you post a [mcve] that demonstrates exactly what you mean by "goes south".  I imagine if you used the definition in the answer and make a `new Sequence<{operation: unknown}>()` you'll at least be able to access the `operation` property of each request, although the type information for each one will be lost, so you'd need that instance check... but if the use case is "loop through and access each one" you probably need that instance check anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You are using  `Sequence.requests` which is typed as `BaseRequest[]`, so if you want to preserve the type you would need to make `Sequence` generic as well.

e.g.

```js
class Sequence<T extends BaseRequest> {
  requests: T[];

  add(request: T) {
    this.requests.push(request);
  }

  merge(sequence: Sequence<T>) {
    this.requests = this.requests.concat(sequence.requests);
  }
}
```

```js
let request = RequestBuilder(params);
let sequence = new Sequence<CreateJobRequest>();
sequence.requests.push(request);
```

Note that this would also affect the typing of `merge`, because you cannot merge just any array of requests.